# Arduino serial port not found

Tags: drivers, 13.10, xubuntu, serial-port, arduino

I'm on Xububtu 13.10 64 bit. I installed Arduino IDE from the software. I have Arduino uno board. when I try to execute any code, I get this error

[image]

Is there a driver missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error returned when you haven't specified the serial port to use.

First, make sure your Uno is plugged into the laptop through the USB port. Then, in the Arduino IDE, make sure you select the serial port under the Tools>Serial Port menu. Also, make sure you've selected the correct board under the Toold>Board menu. After this, if you try compiling and uploading, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*COM1* is a windows port name. Linux port names are like */dev/ttyS0*

Perhaps open the menu as it says in the error message and pick the port that is connected to your device.